# Macbook pro (retina, early 2015) battery charging problem

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I was working with my Apple Macbook pro (retina, early 2015) last night when I suddenly realized that battery is not charging while adapter is plugged in. I searched in the net and found there is a possible solution by resetting SMC. I did but nothing got better and I ran an Apple Diagnostics test and the verdict was reference code PPT002 stating that the battery will need to be replaced soon. On the other hand what confuses me is that battery health information in System Report is Normal. Some screenshots are attached below. Any sort of comments and/or ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is recommended to contact Apple authorised service provider and get your MacBook Pro inspected by a technician. If you bought an AppleCare, you may be eligible for free service and repairs.

Comment: That is definitely not normal behavior. I have the same model MBP as you do with more cycles on it and it has never done anything of that sort to me. I would recommend, as @NimeshNeema did, that you get your MacBook Pro checked out by Apple Support or a computer technician. Apple offers free support on their website, and their representatives are generally very helpful.